# GParse call BackendService async

Tags: groovy, concurrency, parallel-processing, pool, gpars

I'm trying to implement asynchronism in the backend calls, I've been reading and it seems that GParse is a good library to implement this, but it's not clear to me how i can implement this in a correct way. Can anyone help me? This is my example:

```
    def itemsResults
    def locationResults
    def itemsNearLocation
    GParsPool.withPool {
        itemsResults = {searchMyItems()}.async().call()
        locationResults = {getLocations()}.async().call()
        itemsNearLocation = {getItemsNear(locationResults)}.async().call() // i need locationresults answer in order to call this service

    }
    model.putAll(["items": itemsResults, 
                  "itemsNearLocation":itemsNearLocation])

    return "myView"
```

So, i need to call 2 apis call and then in the third one i need to use one of the response called async before, and finally add this to my model. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Might be a good case for [DataFlows](http://www.gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataflow.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use GPars dataflows for this...  Something like this should work I believe (not tried it though):

```
import groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflows
import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.task

final def df = new Dataflows()

task {
    df.itemsResults = searchMyItems()
}

task {
    df.locationResults = getLocations()
}

task {
    df.itemsNearLocation = getItemsNear(df.locationResults)
}

def lastTask = task {
    model.putAll(["items": df.itemsResults, 
                  "itemsNearLocation":df.itemsNearLocation])
}

lastTask.join()
```

Comment: can you use `final` as var name? :)

Comment: @injecteer, good catch. it is a reserved keyword. May be it was quick reply. But it is to show how it can be achieved what OP is looking for.

Comment: @injecteer hehehe, fixed ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks for the help! How can i return the view when all taks are finished? I edited my code